# Camel Context changes not reflect in hawtio

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse, hawtio

I have Camel running in my JVM and hawtio connected to it. I can see Camel details in the hawtio JMX tab. When I change anything in camelcontex.xml and restart my karaf that changes didn't reflect in hawtio.

So I am not able to debug my route hawtio.

Can some one please suggest any configuration, so that changes start reflecting in hawtio and I could debug my Route through hawtio.

My CamelContex.xml

```
<route id="cbr-route">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file://C:/temp/camel"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="Receiving order ${file:name}"/>
            <choice id="_choice1">
                <when id="_when1">
                    <xpath id="_xpath1">/order/customer/country = 'UK'</xpath>
                    <log id="_log2" message="Sending order ${file:name} to the UK"/>
                    <to id="_to1" uri="file:work/cbr/output/uk"/>
                </when>
                <when id="_when2">
                    <xpath id="_xpath2">/order/customer/country = 'US'</xpath>
                    <log id="_log3" message="Sending order ${file:name} to the US"/>
                    <to id="_to2" uri="file:work/cbr/output/us"/>
                </when>
                <otherwise id="_otherwise1">
                    <log id="_log4" message="Sending order ${file:name} to another country"/>
                    <to id="_to3" uri="file:work/cbr/output/others"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
            <log id="_log5" message="Done processing ${file:name}"/>
        </route>
```

hawtio source tab route

```
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="cbr-route">
        <from uri="file:work/cbr/input" id="_from1"/>
        <log message="Receiving order ${file:name}" id="_log1"/>
        <choice id="_choice1">
            <when id="_when1">
                <xpath>/order/customer/country = 'UK'</xpath>
                <log message="Sending order ${file:name} to the UK" id="_log2"/>
                <to uri="file:work/cbr/output/uk" id="_to1"/>
            </when>
            <when id="_when2">
                <xpath>/order/customer/country = 'US'</xpath>
                <log message="Sending order ${file:name} to the US" id="_log3"/>
                <to uri="file:work/cbr/output/us" id="_to2"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise id="_otherwise1">
                <log message="Sending order ${file:name} to another country" id="_log4"/>
                <to uri="file:work/cbr/output/others" id="_to3"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <log message="Done processing ${file:name}" id="_log5"/>
    </route>
```

Thank you so much in Advanced.

Comment: I tried to stop and start all hawtio bundles , but not working

Comment: Karaf 6.3
Apache Camel 2.17.0
hawtio 1.4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you change the Camel XML from the hawtio web console, then those changes are not persistent, they are only changed at runtime in memory. If you need persistent changes you need to change in your source code, rebuild and redeploy to karaf.

However Karaf supports deploying a single xml file as well by copying it to the deploy folder. Then you can do changes to that file and save, and karaf should detect the file change and redeploy automatic.

Comment: Thank you so much @Claus Ibsen , its an honour  talking you . I am new to Apache Camel and Fuse and I was trying to deploy two Fuse project in Jboss Studio through add project to server. Could you please point me how I could add 2-3 projects in Karaf through Jboss Studio.     2.) Also I tried various time changing in source code rebuild and redeploy to Karaf , even I removed data folder but still that source code change does not reflect in hawtio. Do I need to change any configuration file to reflect changed in hawtio. please suggest your valuable thoughts

Comment: @Arun be sure to mark your bundle with `-SNAPSHOT` version in the POM. If you redeploy same stable version it may not reload everything.